# Update data from QuickBooks API from commandline

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We are setting up a new we application which is required to access QuickBooks APIs to update customers' data, invoices and payments. We are trying to update customer data or customer invoice data periodically from application backend which is a java program or from terminal (Linux). 
This java program periodically posts requests QuickBooks to get recent data about customer data and invoices.

Please let me know if there is any possibility to acheive this requirement. As I'm new to QuickBooks and it's APIs.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: QuickBooks Online, or QuickBooks for Windows?  This is such a basic information, it boggles the mind why no one seems to include this whenever they ask questions... *sigh*

Comment: This question related to QuickBooks Online. This requirement was solved by storing apptoken and apptoken secret keys from the response from QuickBooks OAuth. Thanks for your suggestion and reply.